Upgrade Angular v15 to v16
After updating my Angular project from version 15 to version 16, I got the following errors:
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:79:12 - error NG6002: 'TranslateModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 79   imports: [
               ~
 80     HttpClientModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 89     RecaptchaFormsModule
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 90   ],
    ~~~

  node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/public_api.d.ts:20:22
    20 export declare class TranslateModule {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@ngx-translate/core) which declares TranslateModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:86:5 - error NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.

86     SharedModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:88:5 - error NG6002: 'RecaptchaModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

88     RecaptchaModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ng-recaptcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class RecaptchaModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ng-recaptcha) which declares RecaptchaModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if 
a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:89:5 - error NG6002: 'RecaptchaFormsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

89     RecaptchaFormsModule
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ng-recaptcha/recaptcha/recaptcha-forms.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class RecaptchaFormsModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ng-recaptcha) which declares RecaptchaFormsModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/papers/papers.module.ts:14:12 - error NG6002: 'ScrollToModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 14   imports: [
               ~
 15     ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 26     CommonModule
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 27   ],
    ~~~

  node_modules/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to/lib/scroll-to.module.d.ts:3:22
    3 export declare class ScrollToModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) which declares ScrollToModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:11:12 - error NG6002: 'CarouselModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 11   imports: [
               ~
 12     CommonModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 16     CoreModule
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 17   ],
    ~~~

  node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.module.d.ts:2:22
    2 export declare class CarouselModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ngx-bootstrap/carousel) which declares CarouselModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. 
Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:11:12 - error NG6002: 'TooltipModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 11   imports: [
               ~
 12     CommonModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 16     CoreModule
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 17   ],
    ~~~

  node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.module.d.ts:2:22
    2 export declare class TooltipModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ngx-bootstrap/tooltip) which declares TooltipModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.

How can I solve this problem please?
I've tried to update every package in my project but to no avail.

For v16, you'll have to upgrade those reported libraries to Ivy compatible versions (if available).
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78946861/7312347
